# Jetty doesn't start in pre-integration-test phase (Maven)

Tags: java, maven, testing, jetty, maven-failsafe-plugin

I'm trying to use Maven Failsafe Plugin to run my functional/integration tests, according to this guide: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing, chapter *Using the Maven Failsafe Plugin to run Integration Tests*

However, jetty doesn't start in the pre-integration-test phase and thus all the tests fail. Is there any problem in the following POM configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
          <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.7</version>
    <configuration>

          <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
              <port>8080</port>
              <maxIdleTime>3600000</maxIdleTime>
            </connector>
          </connectors>

        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
        <scanIntervalSeconds>3</scanIntervalSeconds>
        <scanTargetPatterns>
            <scanTargetPattern>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.jsp</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.html</exclude>
                </excludes>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.page</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                </includes>
            </scanTargetPattern>
        </scanTargetPatterns>
        <execution>
            <execution>
                <id>start-jetty</id>
                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run-exploded</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                  <daemon>true</daemon>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>stop-jetty</id>
                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>stop</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </execution>

    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I run the integration tests by `mvn verify`

Comment: Please add the output of `mvn -X verify`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why - first I put the `execution` tags inside another `execution` tag (instead of `executions`) and then this `executions` block shouldn't be inside `configuration` tag, but outside of it, right inside the `plugin` tag.